# Oracle - Get authenticated user

Tags: oracle, iis

My MVC application connects in Oracle database. We created a lot of triggers to save all data changed by users.

inside the trigger, we used the code bellow to get authentcated user:

```
UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER'))
```

When i'm running my application in localhost, the database get the correct user, but when i plublish it on server (IIS), the database always get as user the application pool name.

Is there some IIS configuration that i need to set to get "Windows authentication" user? Is there another way to get this information inside oracle function/trigger?

Answer (score 4):

You would realistically want to use a [secure application context](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/app_context.htm#DBSEG011) which is basically a user-controlled context unlike the system-controlled `USERENV` context.  When the application code gets a connection from the pool, it would call a stored procedure that sets the application username in the new application context.  Your triggers would then reference the new context rather than `USERENV`.  Your application needs to ensure that the context is set appropriately every time a connection is acquired from the pool-- if the application fails to set the context correctly, your triggers will get the wrong information.

If you don't want to create your own context, you could use the `CLIENT_IDENTIFIER` in `USERENV` which you can set via `dbms_session` whenever you get a connection from the pool.  Functionally, this is basically identical to creating your own context.  The nice thing about creating your own context, though, is that you can seamlessly add attributes in the future as you identify the need (i.e. adding the IP address of the client browser or a tier attribute if you have gold, silver, and bronze customers).

There are alternate ways to approach the problem such as using [proxy authentication](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/proxya.htm).  In general, though, that's not going to work as well with connection pools particularly when you have very large numbers of users.

Comment: Many languages have direct calls to set `CLIENT_IDENTIFIER`, e.g. in PHP OCI8 you can use `oci_set_client_identifier($c, 'myname')`.  And your SQL queries would use `... where sys_context('userenv', 'client_identifier') = 'myname';`  Check out the article https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/php-web-auditing-171451.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers. I am now checking how to update this value through Asp.Net.